# JavaScript : Iteration over Object (not able to return answer)

Tags: javascript, object

I want to iterate throughout the object to traverse all the values in the given object.

I have tried and was quite successful but as I'm using a function so I need to return the answer but I'm not able to do so. Below is my code that I tried.

```js
var d = {
    name: "Simon",
    age: "20",
    clothing: {
        style: "simple",
        hipster: false
    }
}
function deep(target){
    if(typeof target === 'object'){
      for(const key in target){
        deep(target[key]);
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log(target);
    }
  }
  deep(d);
```

my answer is correct as it prints like:

```
Simon
20
simple
false
```

I just need to return this answer.

Comment: yes i have tried it

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an array, push items in that array. Finally join the array with `\n` and return that:

```js
var d = {
    name: "Simon",
    age: "20",
    clothing: {
        style: "simple",
        hipster: false
    }
}
var res = [];
function deep(target){
  if(typeof target === 'object'){
    for(const key in target){
      deep(target[key]);
    }
  }
  else{
    res.push(target);
  }
  return res.join('\n');
}
console.log(deep(d));
```

Comment: @Anonymus read the code carefully, he's returning the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just being careful of what you return and how you merge the results of recursion. You shouldn't need an external array:

```js
var d = {
    name: "Simon",
    age: "20",
    clothing: {
        style: "simple",
        hipster: false
    }
}

function deep(target){
    return typeof target !== 'object' || target === null
        ? [target]
        : [].concat(...Object.values(target).map(deep))
}

console.log(deep(d))
```

If you need a string, of course, you can just `join()` the array.